# How to launch browser in iOS Simulator from command line?

Tags: ios, script, web-browser

I want to launch the browser in iOS Simulator from the Terminal with specified URL.

Is there any command for it? So that I can write in a script which will take URL as argument and launch simulator with browser and URL open on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari -u "http://google.com/"`

<sup>Yes this really is one long command — make sure to run it all. Replace `google.com` with actual website, and `iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk` with the relevant version of the simulator that you're using.</sup>

Comment: You can easily pass in the target website if you replace `"http://google.com"` with `"$*"`, and you save this as a shell script (e.g. `~/launch_ios_browser.sh`, then `chmod 700` the file). Then you can go to localhost using `~/launch_ios_browser.sh http://apple.com`

Comment: @grgarside Any idea how to do this in the latest Xcode with the iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 5):

On Xcode6 simctl was introduced so you can just open the terminal and type:

`xcrun simctl openurl booted "https://google.com"`

Comment: Initially I was getting an error (`xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH`) so I needed to launch XCode (`Version 11.6 (11E708)`) and set the `Command Line Tools` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36726612/1449799

Answer (score 3):

The path has changed for Xcode 6.0 (OS X Yosemite) and now it's:

`alias simulator='open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use a temp file that redirects to the URL you want, then opening this file in the simulator.  This isn't necessarily the best way, but it is a shorter command.

`echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content='0;url=http://apple.stackexchange.com'>" > ~/tmp/openURL.html; open ~/tmp/openURL.html -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/`

As in the other answers, you can replace the URL (I put apple.stackexchange.com) with whatever you want. Just make sure you put http:// because `open` interprets arguments as filesystem paths by default.

Sadly, the bulk of the command is just the path to the iPhone Simulator bundle.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what to do : Go to Finder and run `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal`, and paste in the following code:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

That should help if you use XCODE, or a iOS Simulator.

Comment: This doesn't open to the browser, let alone a specified URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
osascript -e "tell application \"iPhone Simulator\" to activate"
```

Comment: This does start the Simulator, but how does it start the browser inside the simulator as well?