# How to launch an iOS Simulator with Safari open using a single command?

Tags: terminal, xcode, xcode-simulator

I am looking for a solution to launch the iOS Simulator from command line with Safari launched by default. Launching the simulator from command line is easy. So is the launching of Safari. But I want (rather need) to do this in a single command line statement which will be executed from some third party tool. Is there a possible way to do this?

I have Xcode 6.0 installed with me on OS X version 10.9.4. For now, I am starting the simulator using `xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)"`

But I am not able to figure out if we can pass extra arguments to this statement so that it launches Safari as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch browser in iOS Simulator from command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117064/how-to-launch-browser-in-ios-simulator-from-command-line)

Comment: I have seen that thread already and it is not what I am looking for. I don't want to go to any URL. Just launch the Mobile Safari App. And look at the answer provided for xCode 6.0 which doesn't talks about launching the safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a webpage in safari using :

```
xcrun simctl openurl <Device UDID> http://www.google.com
```

You can determine the Device UDID by running xcrun `simctl list`

Just run both command using the `&&` operator.

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)" && xcrun simctl openurl <Device UDID> http://www.google.com
```

Comment: It just launches the simulator and does nothing else. Do I need to replace Safari with something else?

Comment: I think @VivekVDwivedi meant MobileSafari, not the desktop one... `open -a` opens the desktop applications.

Comment: Yes, I meant the mobile safari. I am working on automation but unable to find a way till now to launch the mobile safari with simulator in a single command. I have a shell script which does the job, but I am still researching to get this shell script out.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @VivekVDwivedi You probably need to add a `sleep 5` in between the two commands to wait for the simulator to boot.